# Before insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to create a before insert trigger that will prevent creating an order task if the order item has a checkbox not marked.  If it is checked then let the task get created.  It throws the error when the checkbox is checked or not checked.

Not sure what I'm missing.

```
 trigger PreventOrderTaskCreationonOrderItem on Order_Task__c(before insert) {
    for (order_Task__c o: trigger.new) {
        System.debug(o.Order_Phase__r.Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c);

        If(o.Order_Phase__r.Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c == FALSE) {
            o.addError('You cannot add an order project category to this item.');
        }
        Else {}

    }
}
```

Comment: Jellybea, it helps a LOT if you include the type of error  and where it happens (debug logs, line nr).

Answer (score 2):

The relationship fields are not populated in triggers. You are most likely getting a "Null Pointer Exception" when executing the code: `o.Order_Phase__r.Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c`. This is because `o.Order_Phase__r` is null, hence the NPE

If you need to reference other objects in a trigger you will need to do a SOQL query to get the results. See the example below, which is completely untested but hopefully will give you the idea of what you need to do.

```
trigger PreventOrderTaskCreationonOrderItem on Order_Task__c (before insert) {

    List<Id> orderPhaseIds = new List<Id>();
    for (order_Task__c o: trigger.new){
        orderPhaseIds.add(o.Order_Phase__c);
    }
    Map<Id, Order_Phase__c> opMap = Map<Id, Order_Phase__c>();
    if (orderPhaseIds.size() > 0) {
        for (Order_Phase__c op : [select Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c from Order_Phase__c where Id in:orderPhaseIds]) {
            opMap.put(op.Id, op);
        }
    }
    for (order_Task__c o: trigger.new){
        Order_Phase__c op = opMap.get(o.Order_Phase__c);
        if(op != null && op.Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c == FALSE) {
            o.addError('You cannot add an order project category to this item.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess you're receiving a System.NullPointerReference exception because you're trying to access fields which are not available to the trigger.

```
o.Order_Phase__r.Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c
```

This information isn't available unless you get it from the database.

- you can loop through all your Order_Task__c records and store their Order_Phase__c fields in a set.
- you can query the Order_Phase__c object for all the ID's in the above set, including the Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c field, and store the results in a map
- iterating your order_Task__C records again you can now fetch the necesairy boolean field from the map through the Order_Phase__c  field and execute your logic.